# Why does my img size differently on two different pages?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

While viewing this page http://peteredesigns.com on Safari on an iPhone 6s, in portrait orientation, the image at the top that says "Peter E Designs" spans about 75% of the page, as it is supposed to, as its CSS is:

```
#wrapper #header a img {
width: 735px;
text-align: center;
}
```

However, when I go to this page, http://peteredesigns.com/transformations-gallery/, with same orientation and browser, the img expands to be very large. Why does this happen? I would like this image to stay the same width on every page.

I have tried:
-- setting the body width to 980px, which is what browsersize.com says is the width of my iPhone portrait browser width
-- I then set body max-width to 980px so that nothing on the page could cause the page to expand

```
body {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 980px;
    max-width:980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I also set the img width to 735px as posted above, so that it would not expand. But between these two pages it does.

Can anyone explain why the image changes width between these two pages?

My expected results are that my img stays the same width on every page while being viewed on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the different content on the page is blowing out the page width and affecting zooming.

Make the following changes and you should be alright.  I set everything to 100%, but you can alter these percents based on need.

```
#wrapper #header a img {
    width: 100%; /*instead of 735px*/
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%; /*instead of 75%*/
}

body {
    width: 100%; /* instead of 980px;*/
}
```

On the homepage, you should alter class="entry-content" img to have a width of 100% as well so the page doesn't get blown out.

You can set pixel max-width on all of these elements as well to ensure desktop viewing has not changed.